# What is the reason behind this infinite loop?

Tags: java

I'm new to java, I wrote a code to practice loops, and here is it:

```
public class scratch {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int value = 0;
        boolean myBoolean = (value < 5);

        while(myBoolean) {

            System.out.println(value);
            value = value + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get an infinite loop, but if i change the "while" argument like this:

```
public class scratch {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int value = 0;
        boolean myBoolean = (value < 5);

        while(value < 5) {

            System.out.println(value);
            value = value + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

it works and here is the output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Can you please tell me what I'm missing here, thank you!

Comment: Doesn't this small experiment make it quite clear that your boolean variable get's evaluated once and doesn't care anymore how it was initialized (i.e. it doesn't update itself when `value` changes)? What is unclear about that?

Comment: In the first case, the value of `myBoolean` does not change when you change `value`. It doesn't in the second case either, but it doesn't matter, because you never use its value.

Comment: Boolean = 0<5 always

Comment: What is there not to understand? Please work through some tutorial explaining how a `while` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** also reevaluate the `boolean` expression to set your value in the loop body for it to work, like

```
final int LIMIT = 5; // <-- try to avoid magic numbers.
boolean myBoolean = (value < LIMIT); // <-- assigns the result of the expression 
                                    //    `value < LIMIT` to `myBoolean`.
while(myBoolean) {
    System.out.println(value);
    value = value + 1; // <-- value++;
    myBoolean = (value < LIMIT);
}
```

without that last line updating `myBoolean`, when `myBoolean` is `true` it will **always** be `true`.

Comment: What do you mean by avoid magic numbers?
And why did you use the variable LIMIT instead of just writing 5?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you only set "myBolean" once and never change that value again. That is why your loop runs endless.

In the second example you check the value < 5 for every run of your loop.

If you'd move that asignment into your loop it would work too.

```
public class scratch {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int value = 0;
    boolean myBoolean = true;
    while(myBoolean) {
        System.out.println(value);
        value = value + 1;
        myBoolean = (value < 5);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In *both* examples, `myBoolean` is only set once.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple, in the first case

```
public class scratch {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int value = 0;
        boolean myBoolean = (value < 5);

        while(myBoolean) {

            System.out.println(value);
            value = value + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

You are setting boolean variable to be `boolean myBoolean = (value < 5);` which is true as value is initialized to zero. and you are not changing that later, so you end up in an infinite loop

While in the second case

```
public class scratch {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int value = 0;
        boolean myBoolean = (value < 5);

        while(value < 5) {

            System.out.println(value);
            value = value + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

you are increasing the value in the loop and comparing the value itself for the loop to proceed and hece when value becomes `5` the condition becomes false and the loop terminates.